# modbus android application eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, tcp, modbus

I am new at android. I am trying to run java code program of modbusdroid in eclipse
i did not change any code only downloaded latest version  seroUtils.jar and added to project because it was missing. error log is attached please help me
when i run it in eclipse 
*source* - https://github.com/bigcat/ModbusDroid

```
09-25 17:22:17.806: E/dalvikvm(813): Could not find class 'com.bencatlin.modbusdroid.OldVersion.MbDroidMsgExceptionHandler', referenced from method com.bencatlin.modbusdroid.OldVersion.ModbusDroid.onCreate
09-25 17:22:19.117: E/dalvikvm(813): Could not find class 'com.serotonin.util.queue.ByteQueue', referenced from method com.serotonin.modbus4j.base.ModbusUtils.calculateCRC
09-25 17:22:20.277: E/dalvikvm(813): Could not find class 'com.serotonin.messaging.StreamTransport', referenced from method com.serotonin.modbus4j.ip.tcp.TcpMaster.openConnection
09-25 17:22:20.498: E/dalvikvm(813): Could not find class 'com.serotonin.modbus4j.ip.encap.EncapMessageParser', referenced from method com.serotonin.modbus4j.ip.tcp.TcpMaster.init
09-25 17:22:20.667: E/dalvikvm(813): Could not find class 'com.serotonin.modbus4j.ip.xa.XaMessageParser', referenced from method com.serotonin.modbus4j.ip.tcp.TcpMaster.init
09-25 17:22:20.807: E/dalvikvm(813): Could not find class 'com.serotonin.modbus4j.ip.encap.EncapMessageRequest', referenced from method com.serotonin.modbus4j.ip.tcp.TcpMaster.send
09-25 17:22:20.930: E/dalvikvm(813): Could not find class 'com.serotonin.modbus4j.ip.xa.XaMessageRequest', referenced from method com.serotonin.modbus4j.ip.tcp.TcpMaster.send
09-25 17:22:21.437: E/dalvikvm(813): Could not find class 'com.serotonin.messaging.MessageControl', referenced from method com.serotonin.modbus4j.ModbusMaster.getMessageControl
09-25 17:22:21.797: E/dalvikvm(813): Could not find class 'com.serotonin.messaging.DefaultMessagingExceptionHandler', referenced from method com.serotonin.modbus4j.Modbus.<init>
09-25 17:22:22.002: E/dalvikvm(813): Could not find class 'com.serotonin.messaging.DefaultMessagingExceptionHandler', referenced from method com.serotonin.modbus4j.Modbus.setExceptionHandler
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.serotonin.messaging.DefaultMessagingExceptionHandler
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at com.serotonin.modbus4j.Modbus.<init>(Modbus.java:34)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at com.serotonin.modbus4j.ModbusMaster.<init>(ModbusMaster.java:55)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at com.serotonin.modbus4j.ip.tcp.TcpMaster.<init>(TcpMaster.java:55)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at com.bencatlin.modbusdroid.OldVersion.ModbusTCPMaster.<init>(ModbusTCPMaster.java:23)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at com.bencatlin.modbusdroid.OldVersion.ModbusTCPFactory.createModbusTCPMaster(ModbusTCPFactory.java:12)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at com.bencatlin.modbusdroid.OldVersion.ModbusDroid.onCreate(ModbusDroid.java:426)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-25 17:22:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Display.getRotation` was added in Api level 8 (Froyo 2.2 ). I guess you are using a older device or emulator. Create a new AVD with api level >= 8

Comment: i did that now i have uploaded new log

Comment: I think you have some jar file that has not been included in the build.

Comment: DefaultMessagingExceptionHandler , this and some other classes that you see in the logcat are missing. Are these present in the source code

Comment: code imported import import com.serotonin.messaging.DefaultMessagingExceptionHandler;
import com.serotonin.messaging.MessagingExceptionHandler; see source in question

Comment: I think you need to add the jar modbus4j to your project

Comment: hi i am new in this type of programming. i am trying to read holding registers using modbusj4 but its not working can you help me? i am using these line- `System.out.println(getValue(modbReadLocator)); ModbusResponse response = (ReadResponse)send(request); new ReadInputRegistersRequest(slaveId, readoffset,1 )`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved putting a new seroutils.jar into the 'libraries' tab into 'java build path' and then I've checked the jar into the 'order and export' tab.
It solves the problem permanently.